# How to Preventing an underlying element from scrolling?

Tags: html, css

While learning CSS, I came across a weird situation where I want a fixed sidebar, and the rest of the content is on the right side. Right side content contains navbar and main content. But the problem is if the main content is scrollable then while scrolling from the sidebar, the main content also scroll. How to prevent this behavior?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/BaLrrbp)

**html**

```
 <div id="container">
        <aside class="d-none d-md-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio laborum
            itaque voluptates. Consectetur culpa, temporibus, nisi corporis fuga sunt illo placeat aut debitis modi
            Maiores quas ex eius earum ratione architecto quod incidunt, nobis, reiciendis perferendis alias veniam
            aperiam quibusdam. Eos ipsum molestiae culpa fugit, voluptas dolorem quis repellendus omnis aperiam
            exercitationem aliquid eum?</aside>

        <main>
            <nav>navigation</nav>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum esse minus rem repellat quisquam.
                Consectetur vero molestiae, eius sequi officia sed labore placeat quibusdam adipisci, facilis debitisnobis sunt amet dolores.</div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#container {
  height: 100%;
}
div#container > aside {
  background-color: #e87800;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
div#container > main > nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: seagreen;
}
div#container > main > div {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  div#container > aside {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
  }
  div#container > main {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  div#container > main > nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  div#container > aside {
    width: 300px;
  }
  div#container > main {
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the aside element:

```
overscroll-behavior: contain;
```

More about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior).

Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/ramesh_/pen/zYKWjWO).

Comment: @DeC Are you sure you added the style to the `aside` element?

Comment: @DeC Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ramesh_/pen/zYKWjWO)

Comment: I know it works on codepen but not in the project. I've added ```overscroll-overflow: contain``` inline but still, it is not working.

Comment: It is `overscroll-behavior` not `overscroll-overflow`. Check the browser compatibility.

Comment: still doesn't work with ```overscroll-behavior: contain```